# How to refer to table in lyx

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, lyx, labels, elsarticle

Inside the `float table box` I add `lyx:label` but when inside the text and choose `insert crossreference` and choose the table label the text appears as `??`

The reference to numbered equations appear normally , the problem is in table labels only.

I use `elsarticle` class

Comment: In my LyX the cross reference to tables works without problem with the `elsarticle` class. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) where you have this problem.

Comment: where to put the lable inside table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MWE is the raw opuput of from complete source view in Lyx minus the comments. The label inside the caption is OK. Just after the caption also work, but inside the tabular environment is a wrong place.

```
\documentclass[english]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

A cross reference to table \ref{tab:one}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 This & is & a table \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:one}The caption of table one}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks so much the problem was that label not inside the caption box of table or figure, thank you